# How to change the text color of the typing content in radeditor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, textcolor, radeditor

While adding a text in a RadEditor the text color should be saved in default color. But while editing the radeditor by clicking a button the text color of the newly typing text alone should change. Is there any way in client side?

Answer (score 0):

The tools that color text are designed to work on a selection. This is why you get this behavior. If you select text and change its color things will be fine.

If you want to set defaults for the content area, take a look at this article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-setting-content-area-defaults.html.